# How to obtain and use homography from intrinsic and extrinsic parameters to obtain a birds eye view of an image? And can it be used on a ROI?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, homography

I have an image taken from a vehicle simulated in CARLA of an highway and I want to get a birds eye view of this image where the plane I am interested in is the road plane. The image I am testing on is here
[View from vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncyPt.png)

I know the intrinsic parameters as well as the extrinsic parameters. The intrinsic are just from CARLA and the matrix looks like:

```
intrinsic = [[1236. 0.    512.]
             [0.    1236. 256.]
             [0.    0.    1.]]
```

The extrinsic are estimated using a vanishing point method from the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.03722.pdf). Also the frame convention used in the paper is the same I am using and shown below.

[Frame convention used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP37x.png)

The extrinsic parameters are `roll = 0`, `pitch = -5.0202`, `yaw = 4.3160` and `height = -1.3` where the rotations are described in degrees and the translation is described in meters. The translation wrt. the world frame is only moved in the direction of the Y-axis.

What I have tried so far is described in the paper:

[IPM from paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkn00.png)

But I am thoroughly confused by `a_x, a_z` and `b_x, b_z` and what they should be. For me it is not entirely clear how to apply this homography to an image.

Therefore I also tried using the method described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835415/19858102) but to no avail. I used the homography found with this method in [cv2.warpPerspective()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) which results in:

[Image after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GOPF.png)

The extrinsic parameters are applied in the following fashion to get the homography.

Rotation:

```
def rotation_world_to_cam(roll, pitch, yaw):
    R_r = np.array([[np.cos(roll),  np.sin(roll), 0],
                    [-np.sin(roll), np.cos(roll), 0],
                    [0,             0,            1]])

    R_p = np.array([[1, 0,              0            ],
                    [0, np.cos(pitch),  np.sin(pitch)],
                    [0, -np.sin(pitch), np.cos(pitch)]])

    R_y = np.array([[np.cos(yaw), 0, -np.sin(yaw)],
                    [0,           1, 0           ],
                    [np.sin(yaw), 0, np.cos(yaw)]])
    R_CW = R_r @ R_p @ R_y
    return R_CW
```

Translation:

```
def translation_world_to_cam(height):
   t_CW = np.array([0, height, 0])
   return t_CW
```

Homography:

```
  def homography_world_to_camera(R_CW, t_CW):
    T = np.array([R_CW[:,0], R_CW[:,2], t_CW]).T
    H = self.intrinsic_matrix @ T
    return H
```

Lastly how could I apply it on a ROI in image?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.